# How to mock javax.mail.Transport.send() method without actually sending email?

Tags: java, email, mocking

Code for sending email:

```
    Properties properties = new Properties();
    properties.setProperty("mail.smtp.host", host);
    Session session = Session.getInstance(properties);
    MimeMessage message = new MimeMessage(session);
    message.setFrom(new InternetAddress(from));

    message.setRecipient(RecipientType.TO, new InternetAddress(to));
    message.setSubject(subject);
    message.setText(content);
    session.setDebug(true);

    Transport.send(message);
```

I would like to test whether I am sending email correctly in mock way.
Please help!

Comment: The only way to *know* if you're doing it right, is to actually do it. Send to yourself instead of intended recipient while you're testing. That way you can also check whether the email content is correctly viewable by mail client.

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example test, using JMockit:

```
@Test
public void checkEmailIsSent(@Mocked Transport emailTransport) {
    // Call the code under test which sends email.

    new Verifications() {{
        Message msg;
        Transport.send(msg = withCapture());
        // perform regular asserts on the captured msg
    }};
}
```